# How do I set a custom message id in a mailgun email?

Tags: php, mailgun

How do I set a custom msg id in mailgun, such that the value will be returned in a webhook using PHP?

The documentation provided in their blog post does not show how to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use Mailgun API PHP library and set custom variables like this:

```
$mailgun = new MailgunApi('domain.com', 'key-xxxxxx');

$message = $mailgun->newMessage();
$message->setFrom($array['from_email'], $array['from_name']);
$message->addTo($array['to']);  
$message->setSubject($array['subject']);
$message->setHTML($array['body']);
$message->setText($array['body']);  
$message->addVar('myVariableName', '1234'); 
$message->send();
```

So, the answer for this library is to use `addVar`